# Android App database setup

Tags: android, database, rdbms

I am creating an android app, UI/UX and andoid work are finished. I am new to database setup. Can anyone tell me which type of database I should use to store descent amount of data like signup details and app using details. Should I use DBMS or RDBMS or SQlite? help me. Thank you.

Comment: SQlite is an RDBMS and any RDBMS is a DBMS. You probably want to decide on SQL or NoSQL

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view , you have to use SQLite for android apps.

There are several benefits in SQLite like :

1. SQLite is embedded into every Android device.
2. Using an SQLite database in Android does not require a setup procedure or administration of the database.
3. You only have to define the SQL statements for creating and updating the database. Afterwards the database is automatically managed for you by the Android platform.